# iOS inline blocks are fine, but blocks declared as variables cause memory issues

Tags: ios, objective-c-blocks, exc-bad-access

I have a set of code that looks something like this:

```
if(self.property == A) {
    [self.infoManager getThingA:^(NSString *thing, NSError *error) {
        self.textView.text = thing;
    }];
} else if(self.property == B) {
    [self.infoManager getThingB:^(NSString *thing, NSError *error) {
        self.textView.text = thing;
    }];
}
```

Basically, in both instances, they're just getting a string to publish to a TextView. The string is different based on which method is called.

Being someone who's generally against code duplication, I abstracted this out into a block variable:

```
void (^stringBlock)(NSString *thing, NSError *error) = ^void(NSString *thing, NSError *error) {
    self.textView.text = thing;
}

if(self.property == A) {
    [self.infoManager getThingA:stringBlock];
} else if(self.property == B) {
    [self.infoManager getThingB:stringBlock];
}
```

And all was good for a while. But now I'm getting errors in my unit tests where it appears that stringBlock is being dealloced too early. I think this because I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS after the block is run, and the debugger says that stringBlock is NULL.

I am not explicitly copying the block in my method, or in the unit test.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your overall structure; factoring out a commonly used block into a variable is normal. However, a block that mentions `self` can be troublesome sometimes; why not try using the "weakself" dance and see if things get any better?

Comment: And if that doesn't help, you may have to say more about the context in which all this is happening, as the source of the difficulty may lie elsewhere. You're modifying the interface; are you running this code in a background thread or anything bad like that?

Comment: Agreed with @matt. You can try `__weak MyObject *weakSelf = self;` or even `_strong`. Careful with the retain cycles.

Comment: With the context provided, I see now reason why stringBlock would be deallocated. This seems to be a context issue, perhaps the context in which the block is declared is not the same where getThingx is called. There is really nothing wrong with using self inside the block, UNLESS self also has a reference to the block otherwise it is fine, such as copying the block, but you mentioned you are not doing that.

Comment: There is no logical difference between those two pieces of code. Any crash must be caused by something else you're doing wrong. We do not see the source code of `getThingA:` and `getThingB:`, and maybe you're doing something wrong there. Also, you did not state where the crash is happening so it's hard to know what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

The block you have declared above is called an Independent block (other type is called Inline blocks which are like inline anonymous classes in java). when using independent blocks we need to adhere to few rules.

1.You can't refer to self in Independent block objects. if you need to, you must pass self object to the block as a parameter.

2.You can't access to properties of an object inside an Independent block using dot notation. If you need to do so, use setter and getter methods.

...

so In your case we need to pass the self object to the block as below.

```
void (^stringBlock)(NSString *thing, NSError *error, id self) = 
^void(NSString *thing, NSError *error, id self) {
     self.textView.text = thing;
}
```